# set variable to "print" in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to have an alias to print statement. The following method fails with a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> a = print
```

How can I, if at all, set a new alias for the print statement? 
Python version -> 2.7

Comment: You really shouldn't do this. Just define your special `my_print()` function and use it instead of `print`. One reason is that lots of other code uses `print`, for example to display error information, and you may not be able to see those errors.

Comment: You can do this but first you will have to import the `print_function` in your module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you can't shadow python keywords (which are used to make python "statements" such as `print`, `for`, `exec`, `if`, ...).  However, `print` is special.  To ease compatibility with python3.x, you can drop the print statement by using

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of the module (before any other imports other non-`__future__` imports).

This disables the `print` statement and unshadows the [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print) (which you can then be shadow once more with whatever user defined function you want).  e.g. (from the REPL):

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> print = foo
>>> 
>>> print('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

---

With that said, I think that aliasing builtin functions is generally a bad idea.  Future readers of your code (including yourself) will likely be confused when they try to use this code and `print` doesn't do what they are conditioned to believe.  Remember the zen of python (`import this`):

> ...
>
> Readability counts.
>
> ...

Comment: Good answer! I would also add a [link to the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)

Comment: @alfasin -- Added.  I also elaborated a bit more on what is actually happening here, though I'm not sure it's necessary (and I hopefully didn't obscure the actual answer too much with the minutia -- Thoughts?)